# In Magento how can i maintain image quality when i re-size the image with lower pixel

Tags: magento

I want to show the image as good it is in it's actual size even when i re-size it with lower image pixel.

Comment: good comment from Kalpesh Mehta. You flush the image cache every time you try the new settings, correct? :-)

Answer (score -1):

what? If you resize the picture, the pixel-count is lowered. There is no way to resize an image without loosing quality.

Comment: ya.. but it should be possible that i can maintain certain level of quality.In my case it's i am using "$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(80, 80)->setQuality(500)->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(80, 80)->setQuality(500);".

Comment: setQuality sets the quality of the JPEG ... the value needs to be between 1 and 100!

Comment: it's not mattering much !!! then also i have tried by putting it 100. but, not expected result.

Comment: If you resize it to 80x80px you have 6400 colored dots in your picture. What do you expect? What you can do is to raise the DPI, but standard monitors only show 72dpi, with the new retina displays this changes.